# How can I count on listview item on click?

Tags: android, kotlin, counter, adapter

*In my code im creating persons and go with them into a list per button click.
From this list, It shows all created persons(items) in listview.*

So I want to count for every click. Example:

Im Creating Person Max:

You can see max in listview now

When Im creating a second person

**Im want to count like this:

max count : 0

second person count : 0

Click on Max count++

max count : 1
second person count : 0

**Below is the code:**

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener{ adapterView, view, i, l ->
 Toast.makeText(this, "Item Selected " +personNamelist[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
clickList.add(Person(personNamelist[i], 0))
                    clicks++
```

Comment: You need to give more context about what the problem is here. Where is "max count" being logged? Is it on a different thread? Where is "clicks" defined? You might have a thread safety issue. Or something totally different. What you have seems like a perfectly fine way to increment a variable, but you might be *reading* the value incorrectly (or reading from a thread that sees an old version of the value).

Comment: i didnt add thread yet. 
The problem is, if im clicking on the item "max" its countig for max and second the second person.
If i click on item Max, i want to count the counter for max
If i click on second Person, i want to count the counter for second person.
Not for both

Comment: OK so I think there are a few problems here:

- You are using ListView instead of RecyclerView. Not necessarily related to this problem but you should really switch.

- You are using "setOnItemClickListener" to get callbacks for all items at once. Instead, you should apply individual listeners to each view and get specialized callbacks : "setOnMaxClickListener", "setOnPersonClickListener" etc.

Comment: Yeah ive changed to recycler view now.
But how can i do the "setOnMaxClickListener"?

Comment: You have to write `setOnMaxClickListener` yourself. The sets a listener variable inside the RecyclerView. Then when you are binding your "max" item in `onBindViewHolder` you would do something like `maxItemView.setOnClickListener { onMaxItemClickLisenter.onMaxItemClick }`.